# Git clone with all branches

Tags: git

I did a git clone on a remote url and it cloned the repo locally. I wanted to see what the other branches are on this repo, so I did:

```
git branch -a
```

I see the following:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:My-proj myMac$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/b_1.1
  remotes/origin/b_1.2
  remotes/origin/b_2.0
  remotes/origin/b_2.0.1
  remotes/origin/b_2.0.2
  .....
```

This shows me that I'm currently on master. My questions are:

1. Have I got all the branches also checked out locally?
2. How can I switch to a branch?

I'm fairly new to using Git!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Have I got all the branches

Yes and no, actually you have all the information of the branches on your local repository but all the remote/origin/* branches are "read only". In fact, you need to create "your local branch" that will be linked to a remote branch in order to push on that branch.

> How can I switch to a branch?

You can switch to a branch with :

```
git checkout b_1.1
```

This one will work only if you have only one remote, otherwise you have to specify a remote with :

```
git checkout -b b_1.1 origin/b_1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

> Have I got all the branches also **checked out** locally?

Nope.

> How can I switch to a branch?

For an existing remote branch called `foo`, simply do:

```
 git checkout -b foo origin/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

1) git fetch origin # origin - name of remote repository.

2) git checkout branchName

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you have a complete copy of the repository, including all branches that are on `origin`.
2. `git checkout <branch>`

For more details, see `git help pull` and `git help checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly create the local branch and set it to track a remote branch. You could do it using the command

```
 git branch --track  <name-of-local-branch> origin/<remote-branch>
```

Once the new branch is created, you could switch to the branch using

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

You may refer to my blog for basics of git and sample commands for most frequently used operations available at http://balajikatika-technical.blogspot.com/2014/12/git-reference.html

Comment: ... OR you can do it in a single step: `git checkout -b branchname origin/branchname`